# How to theme table row to link particular column data?

Tags: theming, navigation

I have created a list of table records in admin section using the following code.

```
class userDownloadedFiles extends ControllerBase{ public function userList() {
$header = array(

  array('data' => $this->t('Username'), 'field' => 'name', 'sort' => 'asc'),
  array('data' => $this->t('Email'), 'field' => 'mail', 'sort' => 'asc'),
);

$db = \Drupal::database();
$query = $db->select('users','u');
$query->innerJoin('users_field_data','ufd','u.uid=ufd.uid');
$query->fields('ufd', array('name','mail'));
$table_sort = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')
                    ->orderByHeader($header);
// Limit the rows to 20 for each page.
$pager = $table_sort->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')
                    ->limit(20);
$result = $pager->execute();

// Populate the rows.
$rows = array();
foreach($result as $row) {
  //Get URL to user profile
  $profile_url = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/user/'.$row->uid);

  $rows[] = array('data' => array(
    'name' => "<a href='$profile_url'>$row->name</a>",
    'mail' => $row->mail,
  ));
}

// The table description.
$build = array(
  '#markup' => t('List of users who have downloaded model drawing or requested an account for downloading one.')
);

// Generate the table.
$build['user_info_table'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#empty' =>t('There are no records yet.'),
  '#rows' => $rows,
);

// Finally add the pager.
$build['pager'] = array(
  '#type' => 'pager'
);
return $build;  }}
```

But the a tag used in username column is displayed as it is not appearing as link. This is how it appearing [image]

Please guide me how to make it likable and how would I do it for other columns too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the render element syntax for a [Link element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Link.php/class/Link/8.2.x), like this:

```
$rows[] = array(
  'name' => array(
    '#title' => $row->name,
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#url' => $profile_url
  ),
  'mail' => array(
    '#title' => $row->mail,
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#url' => 'mailto:' .  $row->mail,
  ),
);
```

That way you can stick to a more consistent coding style, i.e. render arrays for presentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your link using FormattableMarkup:

```
use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;

$rows[] = array('data' => array(
  'name' => new FormattableMarkup('<a href=":link">@name</a>', [':link' => $profile_url, '@name' => $row->name]),
  'mail' => $row->mail,
));
```

Comment: Any possible way to make the whole row clickable? Like we can wrap name and mail in the same hyperlink.